Bootstrap 5 dropdown open/close on both click and hover
I am building a dropdown menu using HTML/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery and Bootstrap 5. I want the menu to open/close both on hover and click:

Mouse hovers over the dropdown element, and the menu opens
Mouse leaves the dropdown element, and the menu closes
On list item click, the menu also closes

Bootstrap automatically closes the dropdown menu on list item click, however, since I added in the additional mouse hover functionality, this is no longer working. The menu doesn't close until the user moves the mouse outside the dropdown menu. This makes sense given the code for open/close on hover, but I'm wondering if there's a way to still close the menu when the user actually clicks on an item.
I tried adding a click function to toggle the menu to open/close, and also tried adding data-bs-auto-close="true" to the dropdown element, but neither solution is working.
Has anyone encountered this scenario before or see a potential solution? See below for my code. Please note, for some reason, when I run the code here in S/O, the hover functionality does not work, and so the problem is not effectively demonstrated. However if you run the code in CODEPEN, the problem is clear.


// Hide menu on click solution #1
$(".dropdown").on("click", () => {
  var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
  if (dropdownMenu.is(":visible")) {
    console.log("hide menu");
    dropdownMenu.css("display", "none");
  }
});

// Hide menu on click solution #2
$(".dropdown-menu > li").click(function() {
  console.log("hello");
  $(this).removeClass("show").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
  $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("show");
});
// Show dropdown on mouse hover
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="deep-dive-toggle-container dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="account-toggle-container" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="deep-dive-toggle-text">Account</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="accountDropdown">
    <li id="recap-dropdown-item" class="dropdown-item">Recap</li>
    <li id="account-timeline-dropdown-item" class="dropdown-item">
      Timeline
    </li>
    <li id="breakdowns-dropdown-item" class="dropdown-item">
      Breakdowns
    </li>
    <li id="search-dropdown-item" class="dropdown-item">Search</li>
    <li id="account-posts-dropdown-item" class="dropdown-item">
      Posts
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




You fell into the arrow function trap :-) $(".dropdown").on("click", () => ... - this inside that function is not the clicked element, but window. And therefor var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu"); doesn't find any matching element.

Interesting! Thanks for your reply here, that makes sense now. I tried writing the click listener without an arrow function, and it worked as far as closing the menu on click regardless of whether the mouse was still in hover state. However, after the first click, the hover function stopped working - i.e. the menu stops opening on hover after the user has clicked on an item.

Could have something to do with how you are closing it, I suppose - perhaps you're not setting something correctly, that it needs to work. I would recommend to use the methods provided by BS to open/close dropdowns, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#methods

This threw me for a bit of a loop. I tried a few different things that all lead me largely to the same place.
And I should have known better. I've learned the hard way not to try to change Bootstrap's behaviour without using Bootstrap's methods. You can't just go into it thinking "I know jQuery, I got this", because it's got its own internal system, and it will fight you all the way.
So, consulting Bootstrap's documentation on Dropdowns, they do list the relevant methods and events associated with Dropdowns. This is what you're going to want to work with when you're trying to bend Bootstrap to your will.
Of particular relevance in this case is the toggle method, which the doc. says "Toggles the dropdown menu of a given navbar or tabbed navigation."
In reality, toggle really is a jQuery method, not a Bootstrap implementation, but regardless, the documentation will point you in the right direction on these sorts of things, and ignoring it will cause you endless pain and suffering (part of why I don't generally use Bootstrap as often as I should, even when it would save me a lot of time to do so; both it and myself are too opinionated to get along).
Anyway, working solution below. The hover is a little finnicky, but I'm pretty sure that could be dealt with by putting a slight negative top margin on .dropdown-menu, so there's no gap between it and the .dropdown-toggle during which it might catch a mouseout event.
This is basically just your markup and CSS, but I've wrapped it in a HTML5 boilerplate and imported Bootstrap and its dependencies. The solution was pretty much all JS. Moved it to a JSFiddle, just because Codepen irritates me: https://jsfiddle.net/bd1rxsn5/8/
Second thoughts...
It turns out the finnickiness I was referring to has less to do with an imaginary margin between the toggle and the dropdown, and more to do with the button inside the toggle. Notice that it works reliably if you hover to the right of the button, and then over the button, down to the menu, but if you hover on the button itself, it doesn't necessarily work, and if you hover to the right of the button, it works, but then closes if you don't trace a path over the button to the menu. Let me see if I can record this so you can see what I mean...

I would recommend either, 1. if you really want that button there, try playing around with its z-index. I would probably just absolutely position it relative to the containing .dropdown and z-index it below the [transparent] dropdown, or 2. really, just get rid of the toggle button. It's not actually doing the toggling. If you really like the look of it, use your browser's inspector (right click + inspect element, and copy the relevant bits of CSS from the Computed tab), and use that to simulate the appearance with a static non-Bootstrap element, like a div or something.


Wow this is absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much for your time here - I hadn't seen this until now, apologies for not responding sooner. This worked!

@MickeyVershbow No worries, it gave me time to revise the answer a few or more times  This one threw me for a loop.
